# Asp.net & files modifications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, appdomain

We are changing a file and *uploading* it into the web server.

*Once and for all* , I would like to know how changing files will affect iis's Appdomain

*I currently use website - So i've written from my knowledge.*

what will be the values in `web Application` ?( how does modified files in X will affect Appdomain in iis ? )

```
______________________________|_ Web Application _|___ Web Site _____________

changed Global.asax           |                   |     restarted 
                              |                   |
                              |                   |   
changed web.config            |                   |     restarted 
                              |                   |
                              |                   |
changed CS file               |                   |      nothing
                              |                   |
                              |                   |
changed Aspx file             |                   |      nothing
                              |                   |
                              |                   |
changed App_code(folder) file |                   |     restarted 
                              |                   |
                              |                   |
changed BIN(folder) dll file  |                   |     restarted
```

Comment: Did you investigate those `nothing`s extensively? At least by starting a new session?

Comment: Hi @HenkHolterman. yeah im positive that changing those file categories - affects nothing. ( of course-  the next request will be treated by th new file ...). and of course - I can always be wrong. :-)

Comment: _the next request will be treated by th new file_ - That's not nothing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the question is about affecting appdomain ( restarted or not). thanks. I will make it clearer by edit.

Comment: Not sure, but I think this also depends on whether you are running in debug mode (`<compilation debug="true" />`) or not.

Comment: @Peter production never runs on debug mode.

Comment: IIRC changing an ASPX file has the effect that a new assembly is created for that file upon JIT:ing it. Doing so repeatedly for different files in your application will cause you to have a lot of assemblies loaded, impacting performance.

Comment: Changing ASPX files will cause a restart if the number of compiled files exceeds the web.config value for configuration/system.web/compilation[@numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app pool is recycled when any of the following items are modified:

- web.config
- machine.config
- global.asax
- bin directory
- app_code directory

The app pool may be recycled for other reasons, e.g., by explicitly configuring it to recycle at a specific time or after a certain amount of time.

Modifying static files (.js, .css, .html, .jpg, etc.) will not trigger a recycle unless those files are written to one of the directories mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, question please: **#1)** when you noted about `numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart` - this doesn't true for config files...right ? cause they recycle immediately. **#2)** Also , did you mean for all  files in root/subs (which aren't found in special folders like bin) ? I mean  , changing 15 times a text file under /images - will it restart the appDomain ? **#3)** Also , is this 15 for each file or total 15 changes ?

Comment: One more question please : why increasing this value of numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart can cause memory problems ? its just suppose to save a "change counter" , why is that related to memory pressure ?

Comment: i made a test - changing 20 times a file ( aspx & txt file) and i still got the session....so ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Once loaded, an assembly can only be unloaded by recycling the app pool. Assume your app pool is running, PageA.aspx has been compiled and is loaded in memory (from Temporary ASP.NET Files). If you change PageA, it will be recompiled to a new assembly which will then be loaded. The original PageA assembly is still loaded. Over time, this consumes more and more memory. Page assemblies are relatively small, but if you change many many pages for days on end, your server may experience memory pressure.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Changing the web.config always triggers a recycle. numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart only applies to pages. I don't know what you mean by "I still got the session". Please explain.

Comment: I created a aspx page and in its c# code i created a session. then I changed this aspx ( via file system) 15 times ,  and the session was still the same session - meanning- there wasn't a restart. what am i missing ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir How are you managing sessions? Depending on your session store, it's possible for sessions to survive a recycle. Also, page compilations do not necessarily cause a recycle. How are you determining whether there was a recycle? Are you checking the worker process ID? Or are you assuming that same session ID means no recycle?

Comment: Are we talking about recycle or restart ? recycle will save sessionID  while restart APPdomain will certenlly kill all sessions etc... (and im using inProc sessions).